# Org mode blog post with Jekyll

Tags: org-mode

I saw many post about use org mode to post blog with Jekyll. one method is use emacs to export html with some modified publish function, another method is use a Jekyll plugin to call Org mode API do it directly.

But after some try, both mode not work as expected. method 1 will handle the inline pictures but the output is totally in to the root directory, but I wish it been export to separate directory blog by blog. method 2 actually didn't handle inline pictures at all, so the output html will not include the inline image.

What's the best way to write blog with org mode for Jekyll?

Comment: You need to show the code you used so that people can help you.  What didn't work the way you expected?

Comment: Someone changed their mind about Jekyll and switched to Nikola (I admit I know nothing of) - http://cestlaz.github.io/posts/2016-04-17-emacs-jekyll-nikola/